# Identifying duplicates outside of one-to-one relationship with two columns in Excel

Tags: excel, database, excel-formula

I have two columns, Name and Email. I want to ensure that the each unique Name only has ONE unique email attached to it. I used the formula for the inverse of the this problem (checking if an Email has more than one name attached to it) and it worked. However -- with checking if a Name has more than one unique email attached to it, the last result is incorrect; as 'ABC Company' has two emails attached to it, that it identifies, but the last one that is also 'ABC Company' passes the check.

Picture of my table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8GKO.jpg

Basically I am trying to identify when the values in column A have more than one unique relationship with columns B.

After the first occurrence of a combination(A & B), any of other combinations that include A (Name) that is not attached to first mentioned Email (B) - count as Cannot Use or a duplicate

e.g.

`column 1 | column 2 | result column
bob dave | bob@email.com | OK
chris smith | chris@email.com | OK
bob dave | bobsteve@email.com | Cannot Use`

My current formula is:

`=IF(AND(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2)>1,COUNTIFS(A:A,A2)>COUNTIFS(B:B,B2)),"Cannot use", "OK")`

Any help would be appreciated -- thank you!

Comment: Not an answer to your question - but does that last `ABC Company` have a trailing space on it? Because according to the formula logic, it should be "Cannot use", so something else is causing the behavior you get.

Comment: Do you want duplicates to be flagged as "Cannot Use", or "OK"?

Comment: Hi - No it doesn't have a trailing space, that was my initial thought haha. And I would like the duplicates to be flagged as "Cannot use"

Comment: Why not just do something like `=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)>1,"Cannot use", "OK")`. It'll keep the first instance of a name and flag all others as cannot use, whether their corresponding email address is different or not.

Comment: Because I only need to identify the ones that are unique. Think of a registration that only won't allow you to use a taken username....

Comment: Can you maybe add a second screenshot of what the expected result of your provided table should be?

Answer (score 0):

If duplicates should be tagged as "Cannot use", then it sounds like you don't actually need to consider the corresponding email address, i.e. it doesn't really matter whether the name/email combination is unique or not.

If you just want to keep the first instance of a name, then perhaps use:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)>1,"Cannot use", "OK")
```

[image]